# How can I make 10 dynamic cookies in php with a dynamic $cookieName

Tags: php, cookies, dynamic

How do I set a dynamic $cookieName

```
function setCookieFUNQ($symbol,$cookie_value,$cookie_expiration=600){ // 60*10secs // 86400 = 1 day
    setcookie($symbol, $cookie_value, time() + $cookie_expiration, "/"); 
}

$symbol = "BMW";
$value = "bla bla";

for ($x = 0; $x <= 10; $x++) {
    setCookieFUNQ( "{$x}."_".{$symbol}" , $value );
}
```

The symbol will change too.

I've tried many combinations, and I don't manage to find anything on the web.

I've tried the double $$foo to create a variable for the $cookieName

and i've done a simple contatanation. like this $symbol_'blablabla' but for some reason it only works for the first one.

Comment: you should enable error reporting, that would show error that you calling function without enough parameters

Answer (score 0):

At the end, a simple concatenation worked fine, for both the cookieName and the value:

setCookieFUNQ( $symbol.'_'.$x , $value.$x );